# Extract data from microsoft word to a database table

Tags: java, c#, python, f#, ms-word

We receive word documents that are practically a form. Users fill in the answers to the questions we have in the documents, so essentially just a key-value pair of question and answer.

Now, I would like to extract the answers and store it in the database table mapping to the appropriate column(question). What is the best way to do this? Is there a library that can help me achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a VERY broad question, and the fact that you have included 4 different programming languages in your question suggests that you are not sure where to start. Unfortunately, these kind of questions are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider unzipping the .docx file and extracting the information from the embedded .xml file. You can find out more about the Word 2010 format here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisrae/archive/2010/10/06/where-is-the-documentation-for-office-s-docx-xlsx-pptx-formats-part-2-office-2010.aspx

Comment: Thats is what I had in mind but I wanted to know how other people do it and I am on the right track. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar If that is what you had in mind then I would appreciate you marking my answer as accepted.